# Find the limit of the sequence using the telescopic formula

Tags: calculus, limits

$${X_n}=\lim \limits_{n \to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\!\cdot\!7}+\frac{1}{7\!\cdot\!12}+\frac{1}{12\!\cdot\!17}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(5n-3)(5n+2)}\right)$$
Using partial fraction decomposition I got that  $$\frac{1}{(5n-3)(5n+2)} = \frac{1}{5}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{5n-3}-\frac{1}{5n+2}\right)$$
I am confused at this part and can not find a way to go forward

Comment: $\frac15 \sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{-3+5q}-\frac{1}{-3+5(q+1)}\right)$

Comment: You're almost there.  Now... look and see if you recognize if anything can be cancelled.  Your question title should be a huge hint how to finish... "*using the telescopic...*"  You have $\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{17}+\dots\right)$

Comment: I am left with $$ \frac {1}{2} and \frac {1}{5n+2}  $$

Comment: Yes.  And?  $\frac{1}{5n+2}$ is eventually *very* small, small enough it might as well be zero.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer

Comment: $n$ goes to, not $x$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more suggestive to write the decomposed term as
$$\frac15\left(\frac1{5n-3}-\frac1{5(n+1)-3}\right)$$
Then only the $n=1$ term will remain after telescoping and the limit is $\frac15\cdot\frac12=\frac1{10}$.